# linq groupby plus select returning element type rather than value

Tags: c#, linq

Novice C#, veteran DBA and brand new to LINQ. I'm trying to understand why a select clause, within context of a groupBy, is returning a type name (in this case "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[CasesReportParser.Requisition,System.String]") rather than a field value.

My ultimate confusion, I believe, is generically how to include additional fields in a groupBy result with those additional fields not being grouped on (not otherwise available in g.Key).

Here is the code and it is the conditional, ExamType, on the last line that is returning the type name.  Thank you.

```
var ListFinal = rows
                .GroupBy(l => new { ExamDate = ParseDate(l.ExamDate), l.PatientID, l.PatientFirst, l.PatientLast, l.Birthdate, l.SiteName })
                .Select(g => new {
                    //ExamDate = g.Select(l => l.ExamDate),//.ToString().Substring(0,10), //.ToString().Split(' ')[0]
                    ExamDate = g.Key.ExamDate,
                    PatientID = g.Key.PatientID,
                    PatientFirst = g.Key.PatientFirst,
                    PatientLast = g.Key.PatientLast,
                    Birthdate = g.Key.Birthdate,
                    SiteName = g.Key.SiteName,
                    ReqCount = g.Select(l => l.RequisitionNumber).Distinct().Count(),
                    ExamCount = g.Select(l => l.ExamID).Distinct().Count(),
                    ExamType = (g.Select(l => l.ExamID).Distinct().Count()>1 ? "multiple" : g.Select(l => l.ExamType).ToString())
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add `.First`, because it is returning a collection.

```
g.Select(l => l.ExamType).First().ToString()
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() if you don't want it to exception out on a null value.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson That makes no sense in this case as OP is calling `ToString` which would lead to an NRE when using `FirstOrDefault`, unless you use `FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()`.

Comment: Yes... FirstOrDefaul().ToString().... if whatever it grabs as First(), if it's null and tries to convert it to string, it will exception... FirstOrDefault() will prevent that exception.

Comment: Use Single instead of First (or FirstOrDefault) since Single better conveys the meaning that the collection of ExamType should contain one single item.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson How would a groupby element return no (sub)elements? It would not be present in the result. Every groupby result has at least 1 subelement. If might be when there was any criteria on the subelements.

Comment: @J.vanLangen I didn't say it would'nt return an element... but if the element returned is null, you will get an exception when trying to convert it to string.  It was just a suggestion to use FirstOrDefault instead of First because in my experience, First can cause exceptions if the element happens to be null. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson no, First would only raise an exception when the collection doesn't contain elements. Not if there returned value is null. It's calling `.ToString()` that will raise an exception. If you want to capture that: `.First()?.ToString()` will work fine.

Comment: @J.vanLangen... Okay, then.. go ahead and try and convert a null object to string... J. vanLangen says no exception... not my application.

Comment: Thanks to all for the education - I ended up arriving at a solution shortly after by using ElementAt(0) but I'll change it as I'm assuming the same null (on string conversion, understood) or out-of-range exception potential exists there.

Answer (score 0):

First of `Select` doesn´t return *any* elements at all. In fact it does not even return a **collection**, but an **iterator** that can iterate over a collection.

So just calling `Select` on a collection won´t do anything at all, only calling `MoveNext` on that iterator will perform the query. This can be done in many difefrent ways, one of which is by calling `First` or `FirstOrDefault`, which seems what you should use in your case. `First` will throw an exception if no element was returned, `FirstOrDefault` however will return the default-value for the type of the iterator (`null` for reference-types).

Having said this you probably need this in your `Select`:

```
ExamType = g.Select(l => l.ExamID).Distinct().Count() > 1 ? 
                                   "multiple" : 
                                   g.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ExamType)?.ToString()
```

As `FirstOrDefault` may return `null` you´d get a NullReferenceException, which is why you should use the [?.-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Comment: afaik: A groupby result always contains at least one subelement else it wouldn't appear in the results. So the First cannot raise an exception. (It might when extra criteria is used on the `g.Where().First()`)